# Matriz de confusión en R regresion multiple lineal

Tags: r, rstudio, regresión-lineal

estoy intentando calcular la matriz de confusión mediante R de un dataset con datos del hormigón como muestro a continuación:

```
Observation Resistance  Cement  Additives   Water   

1   212,9   250,83  2,50    230,08  248,63
2   207,3   261,75  2,63    235,07  259,43
3   222,1   250,33  2,51    224,88  248,14
4   270,9   249,00  2,46    223,95  246,83
5   248,3   251,33  2,50    228,98  249,13
6   284,4   292,00  2,92    232,05  289,32
7   217,9   251,83  2,51    227,57  249,62
8   171,9   214,77  2,15    221,85  213,00
9   226,4   248,00  2,47    222,07  245,84
10  254,6   303,29  3,04    239,31  300,48
11  274,5   303,57  3,04    240,32  300,76
```

el código que tengo planteado es el siguiente:

```
datos <- read_excel("Concrete raw.xlsx")
datos$prediction  <- predict(Resistance ~ Cement + Additives + Water , newdata = datos)

matrizConfusion<- confusionMatrix(table(datos$Resistance, datos$prediction))
```

Obtengo un error, que no entiendo por qué se da, ya que soy consciente de que las filas y columnas no son las mismas para mi dataset 'datos'.

```
Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : invalid argument type
```

Cómo debo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He replicado los datos de tu ejemplo y he ejecutado el siguiente código en R:

```
library(caret)
mod <- lm(Resistance ~ Cement + Additives + Water, data = datos)
pred  <- predict(mod , newdata = datos)
matrizConfusion<- confusionMatrix(data = pred, reference = datos$Cement)
```

Lógicamente, el resultado es este error:

```
> matrizConfusion<- confusionMatrix(data = pred, reference = datos$Cement)
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

Esto se debe a que para evaluar un modelo con una matriz de confusión la variable objetivo debe ser codificada como categórica, tanto en los datos de referencia como en la predicción. Si quisieras evaluar con una matriz de confusión este modelo deberías tramificar la variable `Cement` (podrías hacerlo después de ejecutar el modelo y la predicción).

Comment: PD: Si evalúas el código que he escrito, te fijarás en que el modelo obtiene las predicciones exactas (almacenadas en ```pred```). Esto se debe a que se está evaluando el modelo sobre los datos que se utilizaron para entrenarlo. Por otro lado, son muy pocas observaciones para el modelo.